# This is about how to use isar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-isar

When using Isar's `put` or `get`, you need to specify the collection.

```dart
 await isar.writeTxn(() async => isar.userCollections.put(value));
```

However, with this approach, you would need to create a separate function for each collection, which can be quite tedious. Therefore, my question is whether it is better to create a separate collection for each target and create corresponding put and get functions, or to create a single collection with a large number of properties and have only one put and get function.